# Getting error on updating boolean state in Redux

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-tsx

My `state` data:

```js
options: [
      {
        id: 1,
        name: "Sale",
        isTrue: false,
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        name: "New in",
        isTrue: false,
      },
    ],
```

And, in reducers I have:

```js
    closeOptions: (state) => {
      state.options  = state.options.map((item) => (item.isTrue = false));
    },
```

But I am getting error in `state.options` with `red underline` in `vscode`. And, it shows below error:

```
Type 'boolean[]' is not assignable to type 'WritableDraft<{ id: number; name: string; isTrue: boolean; }>[]'.
  Type 'boolean' is not assignable to type 'WritableDraft<{ id: number; name: string; isTrue: boolean; }>'.ts(2322)
```

More,

```
  Unhandled Runtime Error
TypeError: Cannot create property 'isTrue' on boolean 'false'

Source

  105 | closeOptions: (state) => {
> 106 |   state.options = state.options.map((item) => (item.isTrue = false));
      |                                                          ^
  107 | },
```

How can I resolve this issue?

> Whole project in TS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're getting these errors:

```
Type 'boolean[]' is not assignable to type 'WritableDraft<{ id: number; name: string; isTrue: boolean; }>[]'.
Type 'boolean' is not assignable to type 'WritableDraft<{ id: number; name: string; isTrue: boolean; }>'.ts(2322)
```

Because when you use `state.options.map((item) => (item.isTrue = false))` in `closeOptions` it's returning `[false, false]` whose type is `boolean[]` which is completely different from type `WritableDraft<{ id: number; name: string; isTrue: boolean; }>[]`.

Change `closeOptions` function to this:

```
closeOptions: (state) => {
   state.options?.forEach((item) => (item.isTrue = false))
}
```

Comment: Oh, that means I had to return the full object with updated value?

Comment: Exactly! You need to use `forEach` instead of `map`. @ndm.

Comment: Yes absolutely. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Redux Toolkit, you can simply do:

```js
closeOptions: (state) => {
    state.options.forEach((item) => {
        item.isTrue = false;
    });
},
```

Comment: Yes. It's also working. So, it will update the value without return.